# PHP array with added key

Tags: php, arrays

I have code:

```
<?php $array = array(0, 7, 12, 13, 24, 55, 46, 17); 

for ($i = 1; $i < count($array);): ?>

<div>
  <ul>
    <?php for($j = 0; $j < 3 && $i + $j < count($array); ++$j):?>
    <li><?php echo $array[$j + $i] ?></li>
    <?php endfor; $i += $j;?> 
  </ul>
</div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

It creates groups of html pieces:

```
<div>
  <ul>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>12</li>         
  </ul>
</div>    
//etc
```

How should I modify this code to be able to get that html instead:

```
<div>
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#7">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#12">c</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>    
//etc
```

if I would use this array:

```
$array=array(
  "a"=>   "0",
  "b"=>   "7",
  "c"=>   "12",
  "d"=>   "13",
  "e"=>   "24",      
  //etc
);
```

?

I tried to use

```
foreach ($array as $a => $b)
{
  echo '<li><a href="'.$b.'">'.$a.'</a></li>'."\n";
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. Because there is nothing syntactically wrong in `foreach ($array as $a => $b) { echo '<li><a href="'.$b.'">'.$a.'</a></li>'."\n"; }` Also you won't need `\n` at the end because `<li>` will do that for you

Comment: @asprin It creates wrong [html output](http://codepad.org/q9cfZIkH) with repeating.

Comment: Also you are missing a "#" so may be thats what dosen't work?
Try adding # `foreach ($array as $a => $b) { echo '<li><a href=#"'.$b.'">'.$a.'</a></li>'."\n"; }`

Comment: Is it just me or is codepad down? It refuses to load in my system

Comment: Yep, can't open it now, too.

Comment: @Joddy Thanks. However, I'm wrong with something else.

Comment: @YNT - the codepad is back. bit TOO slow though

Comment: Still no luck with codepad. I added a demo in my answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<?php
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $a => $b)
{
  echo '<li><a href="#'.$b.'">'.$a.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
</div>
```

will generate

```
<div>
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#7">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#12">c</a></li>
        ...
        ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Codepad isn't opening in my system so I don't know what output you're getting currently

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/270512e1090622f99bd75fef2207d36a79dffa1d)

Comment: Thanks, `foreach` works itself. But i'm not happy with a result. Looks like codepad is back: http://codepad.org/H65njqaY.

Comment: What result are you getting that your not happy with?

Comment: @redelman431 It creates duplicates of `li` elements: http://codepad.org/H65njqaY.